# Cannot use the unattend argument for Windows Server 2016 setup

Tags: remote-access, setup, command-line-arguments, windows-server-2016

I'm using en_windows_server_2016_updated_feb_2018_x64_dvd_11636692.iso to attempt remotely installing Windows Server 2016 on a Windows Server 2012 machine.

I've created an unattend.xml and setupcomplete.cmd file to use with the installation

```
setup /unattend:e:\unattend.xml /postoobe e:\setupcomplete.cmd
```

This gives me the following error message:

```
The installation process was launched with an invalid command line argument.
```

I followed the command-lines from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-setup-command-line-options

I've tried also injecting the files into the iso to see if it was the file location that was the issue. But, that also didn't work. I need something to work otherwise I lose control of the server after the installation.

Comment: I'm attempting to do it using the new Windows 10 setup parameter /configfile e:\setupconfig.ini and then running the parameters from there. [SetupConfig]
quiet
pkey=12345-12345-12345-12345-12345
postoobe=e:\
unattend

Comment: It failed to use any of the parameters. It still requested the key and prompted me in windows before it restarted. Once the server restarted I've lost control of it. I'll be rolling back in windows server 2012 and going with another recommendation.